# Which files goes to ARM target device

Tags: php, makefile, arm, cross-compiling

I'm trying to compile PHP interpreter for arm and I actually managed to compile it. When I cloned the interpreter from the repository I got this directory called `php-src`which includes everything in it. Then I compiled it using `make` and `./configure` for ARM. My final PHP binary is located at: `php-src/sapi/cli`. My question is: should I copy all of the `php-src` folder into my target ARM device(raspberry pi 3b+) to make the binary work ? Or do I only have to copy some of the folders inside `php-src`and not the entire `php-src`. I tried to move all of the files inside `sapi` to my target raspberry pi and tried to use `php` binary but I got this following error: `-sh: ./php: not found`.  Please feel free to ask more information because I really don't know if enough information is given or not. Note: I compiled my own kernel for raspberry pi using `buildroot`.

Comment: Are you sure you compiled for an ARM target? What does `file` say about your `php` binary (`file ./php`)?

Comment: Yes I am sure and this is the output:                                                                     ```php: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.3, BuildID[sha1]=213b16e5069f00044801798f864fb5a81626dc45, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, with debug_info, not stripped
```

Comment: @RenaudPacalet What do you think now ? Thanks for your reply though.

Comment: OK, it is indeed an ARM binary. But a 32 bits one. If I am not wrong the Raspberry Pi 3b+ is equipped with a 64 bits ARM Cortex-A53, not a 32 bits CPU. Could it be the reason? In order to run 32-bits applications on a 64 bits CPU you need to also install 32 bits libraries. Either try to build `php` for a 64 bits target or check your `buildroot` configuration and make sure you embed the necessary 32 bits libraries.

Comment: Thats' a good point I will try that.